# How to declare bounds of a method that returns an iterator, which utilizes a mutable method of one of its properties to generate values?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I want to create a method that returns an iterator, which utilizes a mutable method of one of its properties to generate values. This property holds a reference to another object.

The compiler shows the following error when I wrote the method:

```
hidden type for `impl Iterator<Item = i32> + '_` captures lifetime that does not appear in bounds
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=71b5046dedeac1c64e86003b8a4e3b54

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut n = 0;
    let mut a = A(&mut n);
    let mut b = B(&mut a);
    b.run_a().for_each(|x| println!("{}", x));
    b.run_a().for_each(|x| println!("{}", x));
}

struct A<'a>(&'a mut i32);

impl A<'_> {
    fn get_item(&mut self, index: usize) -> i32 {
        1
    }
}

struct B<'a, 'b: 'a>(&'a mut A<'b>);

impl B<'_, '_> {
    fn run_a(&mut self) -> impl Iterator<Item = i32> + '_ {
        (0..1).map(|_| self.0.get_item(0))
    }
}
```

For some reason I still don't understand, if `run_a` is not mutable, or struct `A` not holds a reference, it works fine.

If I change `run_a` to return a iterator that lives as much as `&mut self` to compiler accepts the method, but it is capturing `self.0` (I think) so I can call it only once.

```rust
impl<'a, 'b: 'a> B<'a, 'b> {
    fn run_a(&'b mut self) -> impl Iterator<Item = i32> + 'b {
        (0..1).map(|_| self.0.get_item(0))
    }
}
```

I tried to declare that `run_a` will return an iterator that lives less than its `&mut self`, but I got the same error

```rust
impl<'a, 'b: 'a> B<'a, 'b> {
    fn run_a<'c>(&'b mut self) -> impl Iterator<Item = i32> + 'c
    where
        A<'a>: 'b,
        'b: 'c,
    {
        (0..1).map(|_| self.0.get_item(0))
    }
}
```

Comment: I have no better than this https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=55b4cb42743b48a5fe7f5c9d4aeea89c

Comment: If we create an wrapper it works [play.rust](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=322b9e136799c8941718cc99563d74dc). It seems the wrapper has the _"lifetime that does not appear in bounds"_. But I still don't get why return a opaque with lifetime `c` where `b:c` is not enough

Comment: my guess is compiler limitation but I can't be sure, that a lot of lifetime, maybe with polonius it would compile

Comment: [Here's a more minimal example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a7701448f299205d7d19b5b2abaeb351). I replaced `impl Trait` in return type position with `type_alias_impl_trait` to make the lifetimes explicit, and implemented the closure manually to make sure this is not the reason for the error. If we return `MyClosure` explicitly, it works; but with `impl Trait` it does not.